# Can't figure out where a state is being altered

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am using react. Below you will find the only 4 components that are relevant for cartItems or updatedCart. In DataContext.js, in the addToCart() function you will see I have replaced the saveCart() with just `console.log(console.log(cartItems); console.log(updatedCart));`. I invoke the function by pressing the + or - button (addTocart(item.id, /* - */1)) in the CartItem.js component. I really would expect them to be different. However when I check the console both are the same.

I can't provide much more info. I doublechecked almost everything, but really can't figure out what's going on.

To reiterate (or better word) the problem: In my saveCart() function (DataContext) I want to call a function which will need 2 parameters, cartItems and cart or updatedCart. With cartItems being the cart before I press the "+" and cart or updatedCart being the cart after the +1 operation. But both times when I console.log them they are the same, which I don't expect nor can explain.

Example of a cart object: `[{"id":2,"quantity":6},{"id":3,"quantity":2},{"id":1,"quantity":2}]`

DataContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import backbase from '../../config/backbaseClient';

const DataContext = createContext({});

export const DataProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser') || null) || null)
    const [ fetchError, setFetchError ] = useState(null)
    const [ fetchUserError, setFetchUserError ] = useState(null)
    const [ products, setProducts ] = useState(null)

    const fetchCurrentUser = async () => {
        
        const { data: { user }, error } = await backbase.auth.getUser()

        if (error) {
            setCurrentUser(null)
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', null);
            setFetchUserError('could not fetch user')
            console.log(error)
        }

        if (user) {
            setCurrentUser(user || [] )
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            setFetchUserError(null)
        }

        console.log("userLoad")
    }

    const cartName = `cart_${currentUser?.id || 'anon'}`

    const [ cartItems, setCartItems ] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(cartName) || '[]') || [])

    function getCorProduct(id) {
        if (products) {
            return products?.find(item => item.id === id)
        } else {
            return [];
        }
    }

    function saveCart(cart) {
        if (currentUser) {
            console.log(cartItems)
            console.log(cart)
        } // (not the console.logs I was speaking of)


        /* localStorage.setItem(cartName, JSON.stringify(cart || []));
        setCartItems(cart || [] ) */
        // commenting these out or not doesn't change the problem
    }

    function removeFromCart(id) {
        const updatedCart = cartItems.filter(item => item.id !== id);
        saveCart(updatedCart);
    }

    function addToCart(id, value=1, limit=10) {
        const existingItemIndex = cartItems.findIndex((cartItem) => cartItem.id === id);

        let updatedCart = [];
        let transactionComplete = true;

        if (existingItemIndex !== -1) {
          updatedCart = [...cartItems];
          const quantityNow = updatedCart[existingItemIndex].quantity

          if (value >= 0 && quantityNow <= (Math.min((getCorProduct(id).stock || 0), limit) - value)) {
            updatedCart[existingItemIndex].quantity += value;
          }
          else if (value < 0 && quantityNow >= 2) {
            updatedCart[existingItemIndex].quantity += value;
          }
          else {
            transactionComplete = false;
          }

          
        } else {
          updatedCart = [...cartItems, { id, quantity: Math.min(value, limit) }];
        }

        if (transactionComplete) {
            console.log(cartItems)
            console.log(updatedCart)
            /* saveCart(updatedCart); */ // the 3 lines I was speaking of
        }
    }

    return (
        <DataContext.Provider value={{
            setCurrentUser, currentUser, fetchError, setFetchError, products, setProducts, addToCart, removeFromCart, getCorProduct, cartItems, fetchCurrentUser, fetchUserError
        }}> {}
            {children}
        </DataContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default DataContext;
```

CartItem.js

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import DataContext from './context/DataContext';

const CartItem = ({ item }) => {

    const {removeFromCart} = useContext(DataContext)
    const { getCorProduct } = useContext(DataContext)
    const { addToCart } = useContext(DataContext)

    return (
        <li id="CartItem">
            <article>
                <div>
                    <h3>{getCorProduct(item.id).title}</h3>
                    <p className='total'>{getCorProduct(item.id).price}</p>
                    <p>{getCorProduct(item.id).brand || "no brand"}</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p className='quantity' >Quantity:<button onClick={() => addToCart(item.id, -1)}>-</button> {item.quantity} <button onClick={() => addToCart(item.id, 1)}>+</button></p> 
                    {/* using the 2 buttons from the line above to test */}
                    <button className='remove' onClick={() => removeFromCart(item.id)}>Remove</button>
                </div>
            </article>
        </li>
    )
}

export default CartItem
```

Cart.js

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import DataContext from './context/DataContext';
import CartItem from './CartItem';
import backbase from '../config/backbaseClient';

function Cart() {

    const { cartItems } = useContext(DataContext)

    console.log(cartItems)

    const invokeEdgeFunction = async () => {
      try {
        const { data, error } = await backbase.functions.invoke('stripe-call', { body: 'one', });
        if (error) {
          console.error(error);
        } else {
          window.location.replace(data?.url)
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    return (
        <>
        <ul id='Cart'>
        {cartItems.map((item) => (
            <CartItem key={item.id} item={item} />
        ))}
        </ul>
        <button onClick={invokeEdgeFunction}>Checkout</button>
        </>
    );
    }

export default Cart
```

ProductPage.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import buy1 from "../images/buy-1.jpg";
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import DataContext from './context/DataContext';

const ProductPage = () => {

  const { id } = useParams()
  const { products } = useContext(DataContext)
  const product = (products || []).find(product => (product.id).toString() === id) || []

  const { addToCart } = useContext(DataContext)

  return (
    <main id='ProductPage' className='element-block'>
      <article>
        <div>
          <figure>
            <img src={buy1} alt="" />
            <figcaption>{product.title || "no title"}</figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>{product.title || "no title"}</h2>
          <h3>{product.brand || "no brand"}</h3>
          <h6>{product.price || "no price"}</h6>
          <button onClick={() => addToCart(product.id)}>Add</button>
        </div>
      </article>
    </main>
  )
}

export default ProductPage
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your context is missing the current values beacause it's loosing current state.
I've prepared a simple app which should resolve your problem.

Make the code more cleaner by separating the context behavior.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/red-butterfly-yyp542

**Edit**

To answer why your code does not work as you expect, here by an example [(click to see the code in action)](https://jsfiddle.net/c3ejtua0/):

Let's say you have an array like this:

```js
const items = [{ id: 1, quantity: 1 }, { id: 2, quantity: 1 }, { id: 3, quantity: 1 }];
```

You want to copy it to the new object like this:

```js
const copiedItems = [...items];
```

You learned that the spread operator does not copy a reference. Let's try to modify the copied array:

```js
copiedItems[1].quantity = 3;

// print the values
console.log(items);
console.log(copiedItems);

// output
// [{ id: 1, quantity: 1 }, { id: 2, quantity: 3 }, { id: 3, quantity: 1 }]
// [{ id: 1, quantity: 1 }, { id: 2, quantity: 3 }, { id: 3, quantity: 1 }]
```

You see that as a result you have modified two arrays.
Why is that?

The spread operator does not copy a reference to your array, but the objects inside does have its own references, which means that that references has to be new.

The correct way of doing such a copy with fresh objects inside is to:

```js
const itemsCorrect = [{ id: 1, quantity: 1 }, { id: 2, quantity: 1 }, { id: 3, quantity: 1 }];

// lets make a safe copy
// i am creating new array (through map) and then new item object inside which gaves me new instances
const itemsCorrectCopied = itemsCorrect.map(item => ({ ...item }));

console.log(itemsCorrect);
console.log(itemsCorrectCopied);

// which gaves the following output:
// [{ id: 1, quantity: 1 }, { id: 2, quantity: 1 }, { id: 3, quantity: 1 }]
// [{ id: 1, quantity: 1 }, { id: 2, quantity: 1 }, { id: 3, quantity: 1 }]

// now modify the second index of copied instance
itemsCorrectCopied[1].quantity = 3;

// you expect that only 'copiedItems' will be modified

console.log(itemsCorrect);
console.log(itemsCorrectCopied);

// which gaves the following output:
// [{ id: 1, quantity: 1 }, { id: 2, quantity: 1 }, { id: 3, quantity: 1 }]
// [{ id: 1, quantity: 1 }, { id: 2, quantity: 3 }, { id: 3, quantity: 1 }]
```

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "it's losing current state"?

Comment: The code you gave is a really good rewrite of the code, which will surely be useful. However, I fail to make up what my mistake was or how to fix it in my original code.

to reiterate (or better word) the problem, in my saveCart() function (DataContext) I want To call a function which will need 2 parameters, cartItems and cart or updatedCart. With cartItems being the cart before I press the "+" and cart or updatedCart being the cart after the +1 operation. But both times when I console.log them they are the same, which I don't expect nor can explain. (Added this to the question.)

Comment: @StackerCen look at the answer. I have made edits. This should explain the problem.
If about losing current state:
When you create a function in which you're trying to refer to any data e.g. the state and then you're passing this function to context, or different components you should wrap this function with `useCallback` hook to prevent getting the wrong values from state. WHY?
When the value in state updates, your component may not, and then it's calling the function which has an old, stale value.

Comment: The explanation is very clear, thanks.

One thing I still don't get however. So for example if I press "+" which console.logs both objects, I get the correct stuff logged for quantity+1. However if I don't open the array of objects and press the "+" a second time, and only then open the first console.log the array of objects it returns is now for quantity+2. Just because I didn't open it in the console?

Comment: Yes also, I already saw your comment on the useCallback suggestion in your rewrite, but to my knowledge of useCallback didn't really understand how it would help. Your explanation however really reminds me of a problem I had with currentUser (as you can see above). I temporarily fixed this with localstorage. The declaration used to just be `const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null)` and I would just fetch the user (async) and then setCurrentUser(user). But of course then when I refreshed the page it would load the cart for currentUser = null and not re-render on change.